# Plivo API - pickup phone call

Tags: sip, voip, plivo

I would like to create click2call button on my website - I have users paired with endpoints - so I know which one originates phone call.

Here is scenario I would like to create:

1. User clicks on click2call button.
2. My server sends make_call request to API and it calls to 2nd party
3. Once 2nd party answers call I receive event from Plivo to my answer_url
4. My server sends dial answer with user's endpoint in User Element
5. It starts ringing on user's endpoint - Now I need to pickup call automatically.

How can I do it? Is there any hidden API call / workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Add Call-Info with answer-after parameter to request generated by server in this scenario. Make sure your phone supports it.

Comment: Can you send me some example or link to API? I cannot find it in docs.

Comment: This depends on SIP server you are using. For asterisk see e.g. http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Polycom+auto-answer+config . There is also another way for click2call - sending call command from browser to softphone (via protocol handler like callto:) or to desk phone (some brands support such requests via http).

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I'm using Plivo - I use their API, and they are also my SIP provider. I cannot find anything like this in their docs

Comment: I can't find it either - only API to add custom X-PH- SIP headers that would not be understood by most SIP phones. In case you'd like to try to more direct approach, here is snom call control description: http://wiki.snom.com/FAQ/Can_I_control_my_snom_phone_remotely and for yealink: http://www.3cx.com/blog/docs/call-setup-snom/

Comment: I have AASTRA 6753i phone - I tried to google similar commands for my phone, but it looks like there is none...

Comment: If nothing has changed since 2013 it looks like there is no support for call triggering indeed: http://pbxinaflash.com/community/index.php?threads/click-to-dial-made-easy.12688/ . According to this: https://wiki.noojee.com.au/Noojee_Receptionist/3._Configuration/Auto_Answer_Settings Aastra accepts Alert-Info: info=alert-autoanswer header. I would suggest contacting Plivo directly, it's really weird that company that advertises mainly as click2call service does not provide such basic functionality.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I asked them and they said they don't have this functionality. Do you know about any middle-ware that I can add into my network to modify sip headers? As I can specify "X-PH-CALLINFO=Autoanswer" via Plivo's API, I would like to change it to  "Alert-Info: info=alert-autoanswer". Is there any lightweight router / gateway / proxy that I can use?

Comment: I can't recommend anything. Small suggestion before you would start searching for one: make sure Aastra really works as expected using e.g. SIPp to send INVITE with Alert-info header to it.